# Inappropriate blocking method call - how to eliminate for Reactive webclient and Reactive Redis cache

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, spring-data-redis

This is my first time writing a reactive app, and would like advice on how to make this code more efficient, as it is blocking in some places.  I think at least 1-2 of them may be valid situation in which you would have to block() but I just want to confirm that I am correct in this assumption.

Please see that I have numbered the code in comments for easier reference.

This bit of code when run through my IDE's analyzer, gives a warning `'Inappropriate blocking method call'` at #1.  I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this, right now it seems like I have to block at #1 because I need to get the result from my Redis cache database to determine the branching logic of the rest of the code.

Fyi the purpose of the code is to

> 1. check existence of inventory item in the cache, if present in the cache then return the item
> 2. if the item does not exist in the cache
>    a. query remote api with reactive webclient to get the response (also a blocking call #2)
>    b. convert the response to an inventory item and save it to the cache (also a blocking call #3)

Is there a better way to do this that would eliminate at least #1 block()?  I'm new to this, but right now I'm not seeing a better way to accomplish this flow without having to block() at least in a couple of places.  Thanks for any advice.

```
  public Mono<Inventory> getInventoryResponse(
      String supplierKey, String id, String locationId, String regionCode)
      throws SupplierInventoryServiceException {
    if (!WebConfig.supplierKeyList.contains(supplierKey)) {
      throw new SupplierInventoryServiceException(LogUtil.ERROR_MSG_SUPPLIERKEY);
    }

    reactiveRedisTemplate
        .opsForValue()
        .get(
            getCacheIdString(
                supplierKey,
                id,
                locationId)) 
        .blockOptional() // #1 TODO any way to optimize? blocking here, could be more efficient?
        .ifPresentOrElse(
            (value) -> {
              log.info(
                  "Found id " + id + " in cache, returning cached inventory data");
            },
            () -> {
              log.info(
                  "Cannot find id "
                      + id
                      + " in cache, updating cache and returning cached inventory data");
              log.info("Requesting inventory data for " + id + " from remote api");
              updateCacheForId(id, locationId, regionCode);
            });

    return reactiveRedisTemplate
        .opsForValue()
        .get(getCacheIdString(supplierKey, id, locationId));
  }

  private void updateCacheForId(String id, String locationId, String regionCode) {
    Inventory i =
        supplierInventoryWebClient
            .getInventoryResponse(id, locationId, regionCode)
            .map(InventoryResponse::getResults)
            .map(l -> new Inventory(l.get(0)))
            .block(); // TODO any way to optimize? blocking here, could be more efficient?

    log.info("Updating " + id + " in cache"); // #2 TODO throw exception if false result
    Boolean result =
        reactiveRedisTemplate.opsForValue().set(i.getCacheId(), i, Duration.ofSeconds(20)).block(); // #3 TODO any way to optimize? blocking here, could be more efficient?
  }
```

Comment: .blockOptional(), .block(); --- yea, don't do that. Probably should look at .flatMap.

Comment: Ide only seems to be complaining about the #1 blockOptional().  I did come across this possible solution from the Reactor wiki https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/1756 on how to properly wrap blocking methods.  I'm still trying to wrap my head around that.

Comment: I ithink you're incorrect in that you think you need to block.

Comment: My reasoning is -  if I don't block at #1 (the block() that my IDE is complaining about) - then it will always be empty unless I block() to get the value from the database.  this determines the rest of the flow.  I know there is a reactive way to do the same thing, it's all kind of new to me though, hence this question.

Comment: Why would it always be empty? Motivate that reasoning, use `flatMap`